# Cross compile for RISCV

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling, riscv

I have a C program that I want to compile it for [RISCV ISA](http://riscv.org/). I have followed their instruction for installing the tools. Their tools work correctly and I can compile a "Hello world!" C program and run it. But right now I want to compile another C program that contains multiple files. I tried to change the makefile and instead of using gcc, I replace it with their compiler name `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` but I got:

`Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)`

error, then I tried to set `CC = riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` but I got another error about `pthread`

`unrecognized command line option '-pthread'`

My question is that should I change the make file to use their compiler?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Probably  `-D_REENTRANT` for compiling  and `-lpthread` for linking.

Comment: Something that I forgot to say, my C program is working with Zlib too. when I add CC variable to my makefile, I get error about zlib library, I think I should first compile zlib for RISCV?

Comment: Is the makefile very complicated? If not, could you post the relevant snippets?

Comment: It's a little complicated, but I've post it below

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG := 0
PROFILE := 0
MRSFAST_VERSION := "3.3.1"
BUILD_DATE := "$(shell date)"

all: OPTIMIZE_FLAGS build
debug: DEBUG_FLAGS build
profile: PROFILE_FLAGS build
build: clean-executable SSE_FLAGS compile mrsfast snp_indexer clean

LDFLAGS=#-static
LIBS=-lz -lm -pthread -lpthread
CFLAGS=-fno-pic -DMRSFAST_VERSION=\"$(MRSFAST_VERSION)\" -DBUILD_DATE=\"$(BUILD_DATE)\"

objects=baseFAST.o Sort.o MrsFAST.o Common.o CommandLineParser.o RefGenome.o HashTable.o Reads.o Output.o SNPReader.o  HELP.o

compile: $(objects)

mrsfast:
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Linux)
    gcc -w $(objects) -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} ${LIBS}
else
    gcc -Wl,-no_pie -fno-pic -w $(objects) -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} ${LIBS}
endif

snp_indexer: SNPIndexer.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS} ${LIBS}

clean:
    @rm -f $(objects)
    @rm -f SNPIndexer.o
    @rm -f HELPstub.c
    @rm -f HELPstub.o

clean-executable:
    @rm -f mrsfast

HELP.o:
    @groff -Tascii -man ./HELP.man > HELP
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Linux)
    @ld -r -b binary -o HELP.o HELP
else
    @touch HELPstub.c
    gcc -o HELPstub.o -c HELPstub.c
    ld -r -o HELP.o -sectcreate binary HELP HELP HELPstub.o
endif

DEBUG_FLAGS:
    $(eval CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -ggdb)
    $(eval LIBS = $(LIBS) -ggdb)

OPTIMIZE_FLAGS:
    $(eval CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -O2)

PROFILE_FLAGS:
        $(eval CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -pg -g)
    $(eval LIBS = $(LIBS) -pg -g)

SSE_FLAGS:
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Linux)
ifeq ($(with-sse4),no)
        $(shell echo "-DSSE4=0")
else
            $(eval CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) \
            $(shell gv=`gcc -dumpversion`; \
                    sc=`grep -c "sse4" /proc/cpuinfo`; \
                    echo $$sc.$$gv | awk -F. '{if($$1>0 && $$2>=4 && $$3>=4) print "-DSSE4=1 -msse4.2"; else print "-DSSE4=0"}'))
endif
else
ifeq ($(with-sse4),no)
        $(shell echo "-DSSE4=0")
else
        $(eval CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) \
        $(shell gv=`gcc -dumpversion`; \
                sc=`sysctl -n machdep.cpu.features | grep -c "SSE4"` ;\
                echo $$sc.$$gv | awk -F. '{if($$1>0 && $$2>=4 && $$3>=4) print "-DSSE4=1 -msse4.2"; else print "-DSSE4=0"}'))
endif
endif
```

Comment: What happens if you replace the calls in the Makefile to gcc with $(CC) and use CC = riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc when calling make?

Comment: While this may be an answer for the question, a code dump without explanation is almost always a bad answer.